# Javascript replace null

Tags: javascript

```
var p = "null"
var q = null;
(p == q) //false. as Expected.

p.replace(null, "replaced") // outputs replaced. Not expected.
p.replace("null", "replaced") //outputs replaced. Expected.

q.replace(null, "replaced") // error.  Expected.
q.replace("null", "replaced") //error. Expected.
```

Why? Does replace not differentiate between `"null"` and `null`?

I ask because I ran into a bug in angularjs:

```
replace((pctEncodeSpaces ? null : /%20/g), '+');
```

If for example, someone had a username of `"null"` and it was used as url, it would be replaced with "+" on any `$http` calls. e.g. `GET /user/null`.

Not that this scenario would occur often, but I'm more curious why replace treats `null` and `"null"` as the same thing. Does replace do a .tostring on `null` before it does the replacement? Is this just a quirk of Javascript?

I verified this on both IE and Chrome's implementations of `replace`.

Comment: replace is a method of String and, as such, can only be called on strings.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should remove the q part. That's not what I'm asking about, I realize I should get that error.

Comment: @Rastapopulous yes, that would make the question clearer.   The `q` part is just distracting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is expected according to the spec for **[`replace`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.5.4.11)** (bolded relevant line, or **[page 146 of the ECMA-262 final draft](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)**). The first argument is checked to see if it is a regex and if not, it has `toString()` called on it (well, converted to a string somehow).

> **15.5.4.11 `String.prototype.replace(searchValue, replaceValue)`**
>
> Let string denote the result of converting the this value to a string.
>
> *Cut for brevity*
>
> If`searchValue` is not a regular expression, **let `searchString` be `ToString(searchValue)`** and search string for the first occurrence of
>   `searchString`. Let m be 0.
>
> *Cut for brevity*

Comment: please consider _removing_ text to avoid distraction, not adding it!

Comment: @Alnitak you mean you don't like walls of text?!

Comment: @RussCam yes, there was so much (irrelevant) information in your answer as to render it IMHO useless.

Comment: @Alnitak I'm not sure that the specification for how `replace()` should work is useless, but I agree that it does detract from the main point so will trim it.

Comment: I didn't say that the specification is useless, I said that it made your _answer_ useless - fine distinction ... ;-)

Comment: Well this looks like the right answer! Thanks! Of course this leads me to my next question: null.ToString() is of course undefined and the spec does say that it should be converted to a string, but did the writers of the spec mean to imply that null values should be converted to strings? Not sure if SO is the right place to post such a question.

Comment: @Rastapopulous it's not `null.toString()`, it's `ToString(null)` where `ToString()` as a JS interpreter _internal_ function.  `ToString(null)` is explicitly defined by ES5.

Comment: @Rastapopulous post it as a separate question (although I think that it may have been asked before, so have a search first).

Answer (score 4):

In the [ES5 specification for `String.prototype.replace`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.4.11):

> **15.5.4.11 String.prototype.replace (searchValue, replaceValue)**
>
> ...
>
> If *`searchValue`* is not a regular expression, let *`searchString`* be *`ToString(searchValue)`* and search *`string`* for the first occurrence of *`searchString`*

So, `"".replace(null, XXX)` will indeed convert the `null` to the string `"null"`

Note that `ToString()` does *not* mean `null.toString()` - it's an internal defined operation within the JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: And that is what he expected. The question is around the first line (`p.replace(null, "replaced") // outputs replaced. Not expected.`).

Comment: @alexn that comment relates to my previous answer, which incorrectly focussed on `q`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"null".replace(null, "replaced") // outputs replaced. Not expected.
```

> Does replace not differentiate between "null" and null

This is because parameter 1 of `replace` is converted to *String*.

```
''+null === "null"; // true by cast to string
```

Furthermore, as `replace` takes *RegExp* objects, you can also think about how

```
RegExp(null).toString() === "/null/"; // true
```

Comment: the concatenation is irrelevant - there's probably a `ToString` cast required in the ECMAScript specification.

Comment: @Alnitak , `null == 'null'` and (obviously) `null === 'null'` are both false.

Comment: irrelevant - the real answer is that the `.replace` method _requires_ that the first parameter use the internal `ToString()` cast.  Please go read the ES5 specs.  The `null` RegExp object is a red-herring too - a `null` has no type.

Comment: by which I mean that `null` is not an `instanceof RegExp`, so the implementation of `.replace` cannot test `null` for type equality.  Strictly speaking `typeof null === "object"`.

Answer (score 0):

For the not expected one, there's a simple answer. The null is casted to string by the replace() method.
So that is also an expected action